# Magento 2.2 - Can't log into admin panel

Tags: php, magento2

I'm new to Magento development. I'm currently working on eCommerce site using Magento latest version. I wanted to add custom module to the admin. So I executed

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

command after running the following command,

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Module installed and generated (compiled) code successfully after fixing some errors. But now I see my admin is not working and giving me following error.

```
This page isn’t working

127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

I checked `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` values in core_config_data table and it seems ok. Also I checked `web/cookie/cookie_path` and `web/cookie/cookie_domain` and both are set to `NULL`. I checked with different browser after cleaning var/cache folder. But none of these seems solve the problem.

Also in frontend, the categories(top nav) and product list I created in home page are missing. Please help.

Comment: Finally I solved it by simply disabaling module using following command,

Comment: php bin/magento module:disable Magento_<modulename> and it cleared all generated classes and cache. After that I re enabled the module. Now everything works fine. I have to look into this later.

Comment: which module u disabled?